# Radio On Button onclick for value = No is not closing popup on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code I'm trying to correct because it does not work on IE.  When user clicks the No radio button the the popup should close.  It works on Chrome but not on IE.

```css
.taxCreditHelpPopup {
  margin-left: 51.3%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: 270px;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_FormInput_TaxCredit_In_Register_201">
  <div class="column_label" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_div_111">

    <span class="required-field" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_div_12.1"> * 
     </span> Factura Válida para Crédito Fiscal&nbsp;:
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 10px;" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_div_1112">
    <input tabindex="23" onclick="yesPopUp();" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;" type="radio" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_FormInput_TaxCredit_In_Register_11" name="taxCredit" value="YES" <input tabindex="24" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('taxCreditHelpPopup1').style.display='none';"
      style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 100px;" type="radio" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_FormInput_TaxCredit_In_Register_12" name="taxCredit" value="NO">NO
  </div>
</div>

<div class="taxCreditHelpPopupArrow taxCreditHelpPopup" id="taxCreditHelpPopup1" style="padding: 10px 0px 20px 10px !important;">

  <div class="left_espot" style="font-size:12px !important;">
    <div class="userNameHelpPopupPadding">
      You must register to place an order with IMCA.Select Create Account below and allow 1-2 business days for your account to be setup.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This line seems to be incorrect`<input tabindex="23" onclick="yesPopUp();" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;" type="radio" id="WC_UserRegistrationAddForm_FormInput_TaxCredit_In_Register_11" name="taxCredit" value="YES" <input tabindex="24" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('taxCreditHelpPopup1').style.display='none';"`

Comment: You have an element tag inside another elements tag. That's not allowed in html.

Comment: Also you didn't define `yesPopUp()`